# How to distinguish between operating systems in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have been performing simulations using MATLAB in Windows. However,now I am working on Ubuntu, so when I run a simulation that loads a file which contains needed data:

```
auxiliar_nm1 = load('C:\Users\Miguel\Dropbox\Tesina\Simulaciones\Quadrotor Simulation\M Model 1\auxiliar.txt', 'auxiliar_nm1');
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to read file 'C:\Users\Miguel\Dropbox\Tesina\Simulaciones\Quadrotor Simulation\M Model 1\auxiliar.txt'. No such file or directory.
```

I know that I can just modify the path, so this problem will be solved, but I would like to know if it is possible to determine the operating system in MATLAB, and take a decision based on this parameter, so this script is available for both operating systems (Windows and Ubuntu).

Comment: `ispc`, `isunix`, `ismac`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `computer` gives you what you need:

```
switch computer
    case 'PCWIN'   % 32-bit Windows
        %...
    case 'PCWIN64' % 64-bit Windows
        %...
    case 'GLNXA64' % Linux
        %...
    case 'MACI64'  % Mac
        %...
end
```

Alternatively, you can use the specific functions `ispc`, `isunix` and `ismac`, although note that `isunix` returns true on Mac.

Answer (score 5):

```
os = system_dependent('getos')
```

returns the full string of the OS, which you can parse in a conditional statement to run the desired load command.

```
strncmp(os,'Linux',5)
```

returns 1 if it's Linux (compares the first n characters only, in this case 5).

```
if(strncmp(os,'Linux',5)
  load('linux dependant path')
else
  load('Windows path')
end
```

Comment: I like lmiguelvargasf's answer better, but I need the rep worse :)

Comment: Thank you @dgm, I like your answer too because you get the complete description of the OS, so I have voted your answer. Actually, it could be useful someday using different versions of Windows, for example.

Answer (score 3):

What I have done is:

```
if ispc
    auxiliar_nm1 = load('C:\Users\Miguel\Dropbox\Tesina\Simulaciones\Quadrotor Simulation\M Model 1\auxiliar.txt', 'auxiliar_nm1');
elseif isunix
    auxiliar_nm1 = load('/home/m/Dropbox/Tesina/Simulaciones/Quadrotor Simulation/M Model 1/auxiliar.txt', 'auxiliar_nm1');
end
```

Comment: By the way, it is much safer to use `fullfile` to combine paths as it automatically takes care of the different path separators used between systems. Alternatively, use `filesep` to automatically get the correct path separator for the current OS.

Comment: I was wondering the same because both linux and mac are based on unix, but because of lacking a Mac I can't test it.

Comment: No need to test  – it's clearly stated in the documentation for [`isunix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isunix.html).